# Filling in gaps between sequentially numbered records and updating a status indicator

Tags: sas

In a summarized dataset, I have the `status` of an event at each `hour` after baseline in which it was recorded. I also have the `last hour` the event could have been recorded. I want to create a new dataset with one record for each `hour` from the first through the `last hour`, with the `status` for each record being the one from the last recorded `status`.

Here is an example dataset:

```
data new;
  input hour status last_hour;
  cards;
  2 1 12
  4 1 12
  5 1 12
  6 1 12
  7 0 12
  9 1 12
 10 0 12
;
run;
```

In this case, the first recorded hour was the second, and the last recorded hour was the 10th. The last possible hour to record data was the 12th.

The final dataset should look like so:

```
0 . 12
1 . 12
2 1 12
3 1 12
4 1 12
5 1 12
6 1 12
7 0 12
8 0 12
9 1 12
10 0 12
11 0 12
12 0 12
```

I sort of have it working with this series of data steps, but I'm not sure if there's a cleaner way I'm not seeing.

```
data step1; 
  set new (keep=id hour); 
  by id;
  do hour = 0 to last_hour;
    output;
  end;
run;

proc sort data=step1; 
  by id hour;
run;

proc sql;
  create table step2 as 
    select distinct a.id, a.hour, b.status
      from step1 as a
        left join new as b 
          on a.id = b.id 
             and a.hour = b.hour
    order by a.id, a.hour;
quit;

data step3; 
  set step2; 
  by id hour; 
  retain previous_status;
  if first.id then do;
    previous_status = .;
    if status > . then previous_status = status;
  end;
  if not first.id then do;
    if status = . and previous_status > . then status = previous_status;
    if status > . then previous_status = status;
  end;
run;
```

Comment: You were close. If you actually replace, in your `data step1`, the `do hour = 0 to last_hour;` line with `if first.id then do hour = 0 to 12;`, you should have it working. (Or add `last_hour` to the `keep=` variable list and use it instead of `12`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing your code, it seems you left out of your question the fact that you also have id's. So this is a newer solution that deals with different id's. See further below for my first solution ignoring id's.

Since `last_hour` is always `12`, I left it out of the `have` dataset. It will be added later on.

```
data have;
  input id hour status;
  cards;
1 2 1
1 4 1
1 5 1
1 6 1
1 7 0
1 9 1
1 10 0
2 2 1
2 4 1
2 5 1
2 6 1
2 7 0
2 9 1
2 10 0
;
```

Create a `hours` dataset, just containing numbers 0 thru 12;

```
data hours;
  do i = 0 to 12;
    hour = i;
    output;
  end;
  drop i;
run;
```

Create a temporary dataset that will have the right number of rows (13 rows for every id, with valid `hour` values where they exist in the `have` table).

```
proc sql;
  create table tmp as
    select distinct t1.id, t2.hour, 12 as last_hour
      from have as t1

    cross join 

      (select hour from hours) as t2;
quit;
```

Then use `merge` and `retain` to fill in the missing `hour` column where appropriate.

```
data want;
  merge have
        tmp;
  by id hour;
  retain status_previous;
  if not first.id then do;
    if status ne . then status_previous = status;
    else if status_previous ne . then status = status_previous;
  end;
  if last.id then status_previous = .;
  drop status_previous;
run;
```

[image: Resulting table 1]

### Previous solution (no id's)

If last_hour is always 12, then this should do it:

```
data have;
  input hour status last_hour;
  datalines;
2 1 12
4 1 12
5 1 12
6 1 12
7 0 12
9 1 12
10 0 12
;


data hours;
  do i = 0 to 12;
    hour = i;
    last_hour = 12;
    output;
  end;
  drop i;
run;


data want;
  merge have
        hours;
  by hour;
  retain status_previous;
  if status ne . then status_previous = status;
  else if status_previous ne . then status = status_previous;
  drop status_previous;
run;
```

[image: resulting table 2]